# Is it possible to use php to make a request to another server and get its response?

Tags: php, http, post

For instance `user.php` -> make a post request to a server `http://www.exampe.com`, 
`example.com` redirects to `user.php` and puts some post parameters as well to `user.php`.

I want a function in php to do that?
Anyone with a solution for me?

I cannot use ajax for this.

Comment: Is this always the same `user.php` file? So should the first requested `user.php` file that requests the remote URL get the post parameters that the redirect adds? Even it is started a second time by the redirect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve such functionality using cURL from PHP. Check out the examples in the [PHP documentation](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php).

Answer (score 2):

For simple requests [`file_get_contents()`](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents) will do the trick.

For more complex requirements, you van use [cURL](http://www.php.net/curl), a simple example (returning both headers and resonse body):

```
<?php
function curlPull($url) {
    $cPtr = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($cPtr, array(CURLOPT_URL => $url, CURLOPT_HEADER => true, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true));
    return curl_exec($cPtr);
}
print_r( curlPull('http://www.example.com') );
?>
```

cURL allows for many more options to be tweaked, take a look at [curl_setopt](http://www.php.net/curl_setopt)

Comment: It returns me call to undefined function curl_init()..Do I need to install it first?

Comment: ah, in that case you need to enable the cURL module in your php.ini file. (or use `file_get_contents()` instead)

Answer (score -1):

I'll speculate that eventually such questions as

- Is remote access feasible withOUT cURL? and
- Are asynchronous requests possible?

will arise.  While stackoverflow already abounds in explorations of these, I'll recommend http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/os-php-multitask/

Comment: Yes, Jacco, I confirm:  while I certainly know what it is to feel shame, I have none about the Answer above.  Thank you for the explicit alert that you see it differently.